# Why "response.result is undefined" from Youtube Data Api 3?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-channels

I use Youtube API v3 with jasvascript

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=statistics&forUsername=GameSprout&_h=8&

And i have this simple code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function googleApiClientReady() {
        var viewCount, channelName, subscribers;
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
                part: 'statistics',
                forUsername : 'GameSprout'
            });
            request.execute(function(response) {
                viewCount = response.result.items[0].statistics.viewCount;

            });
        });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

But i have this error :

> TypeError: response.result is undefined

How can fix this problem ?

EDIT

the reponse of :

```
console.log(response)
```

IS :

```
Object {code: 403, message: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.", data: Array[1], error: Object}
code: 403
data: Array[1]
error: Object
message: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What is `response` at that point? Try `console.log(response)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn i edit my post with your idea.

Comment: OK. So now you can see there that the `response` is an object that doesn't have a `result` property, which is why you got the "response.result is undefined" error. Perhaps before you try to use the response you need to test the `response.code` to see whether it indicates an error?

Comment: See the post, we have the answer, thx for your help @nnnnnn :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't set your API key, which is needed for read-only (i.e. without oAuth) calls. Before calling gapi.client.load you must do this:

gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_KEY_HERE");

See:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientsetApiKey

for documentation.

You can also use the `key` parameter on the object passed to your request if you'd rather, but if you're ever doing more than a single call you might as well just set it on your client instance.

Here's a quick intro for obtaining said API key from the cloud console:

https://plus.google.com/+YouTubeDev/posts/BBkwPXP94JB

Comment: Ok it's works fine ! Thx a lot. Last question why google explorer works without a dev key ?

Comment: The api explorer web app would use their key (unless the request needed permissions, in which case you have to use the oAuth button) because a javascript key usually has an origin attached to it (i.e. if your key's origin is example.com then it wouldn't work in the api explorer at all).